# ST_LineMerge doesn't return LineString

Tags: postgis, merge, linestring, multipart

I want to create a LINESTRING from a MULTILINESTRING. However in the following case `ST_MultiLineString` is returned:

```
Select ST_GeometryType(ST_LineMerge(ST_AsText('
MULTILINESTRING(
(-70.52570888 -33.48112668,-70.52552472 -33.48116414),
(-70.52552472 -33.48116414,-70.52453208 -33.48121471,-70.52552472 -33.48116414)
)')));
```

Why is this the case? The linestrings are not self intersecting and are connected. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is probably in accuracy of numeric computing. Removing the last decimal from the Y coordinate of the connecting points is enough for making the query to return LINESTRING

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(
ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING(
(-70.52570888 -33.48112668,-70.52552472 -33.4811641),
(-70.52552472 -33.4811641,-70.52453208 -33.48121471,-70.52552472 -33.48116414)
)')));
```

**EDIT:**

It is possible to drop decimals on-the-fly by using function ST_SnapToGrid:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_SnapToGrid(
    ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING(
    (-70.52570888 -33.48112668,-70.52552472 -33.48116414),
    (-70.52552472 -33.48116414,-70.52453208 -33.48121471,-70.52552472 -33.48116414)
    )'),0.001)));
```

Comment: Interesting! Is there a way that I can remove/ignore the last decimal?

Comment: I don't know but perhaps ST_SnapToGrid() http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/Does-ST-AsText-truncate-or-round-td3553486.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason the lines are not merged is that the second line has the first and third points identical.  This creates a node of degree = 3 at the intersection point, so is not able to be merged by `ST_LineMerge`.